# Scale page to standard letter fomat with CSS

Tags: html, css, django

With regards to a webpage generated using Django, I would like to just print the page as a PDF in chrome. But when I do so, the view does not fit onto a standard 8.5/11 papersize.

Is there a straightforward method of using CSS/HTML to scale items so that when you select print, it will fit everything onto a standard letter size sheet?

So for desktops, if I have something like:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  /* For desktop: */
  .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-3 {width: 25%;}
}
```

Would it be something like this for paper sizes?

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 8.5in) {
  /* For printing: */
  .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-3 {width: 25%;}
}
```

Or is there a much better way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Using `@media print` instead of `@media only screen`? `screen` is for displays...

Comment: That seems to do it! Change it to answer and I'll mark it as such. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When printing, you're dealing with `@media print`, not `@media screen`.